# MySQL: Trigger - Change value for different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, eventtrigger

I've got a table like this

```
 id     firstname   lastname    fullname
 1      alex        car         alex car
 2      tony        table       tony table
```

If the firstname or lastname gets changed I want that the database automatically changes the fullname too.

I tried it with this trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
AFTER UPDATE
   ON mytable FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

    UPDATE `mydb`.`mytable` SET `fullname` = CONCAT(NEW.firstname, " ",NEW.lastname)    

END;
```

But I get this error:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'mytable' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a before update trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger BEFORE UPDATE
   ON mytable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    set new.fullname = CONCAT(NEW.firstname, ' ' , NEW.lastname) ;
END;
```

As a note:  your use of `update` would give you surprising results.  The `update` has not `where` clause so it would set the `fullname` column in all rows in the table.

Comment: I tried it with a BEFORE trigger but it did not work.